# Script has no effect but Python console do (Blender 2.72b)

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

I am writting a script to import a 2D DXF and turn it into 3D.
I have to convert curves into meshes. I manage to do it in Python console but the same Python code in a script has no effect (no errors and curves are not converted).

Here is the code :

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

# Cleaning the scene
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=True)

# Importing DXF file
bpy.ops.import_scene.dxf('INVOKE_DEFAULT') # if i use Blender GUI
#bpy.ops.import_scene.dxf(filepath="/home/liquidus88/model.dxf") #if i do not use Blender GUI (start from terminal)

# Converting curves to meshes
for obj in scene.objects:
    scene.objects.active = obj
    obj.select = True
    bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
    obj.select = False

bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```

This code work (curves are converted) in these cases:

- I run it in Python console
- I run it as a script without the Blender GUI (in terminal with `blender --background --python script.py`)

And does not work (curves are NOT converted) in these cases:

- I run it from Blender text editor with the "Run script" button
- I convert it as an addon and run it by using the addon

I really need to be able to use this code as an addon, any idea why it does not work in the cases i mentioned above ?